# How to know the SSH key's length?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, key, ssh-keys, openssh

How to know the SSH key's length?

I'm getting the following error for my `git pull` just recently,

```
$ git pull
> GitLab: Your SSH key must be at least 2048 bits.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

where everything had been working fine before.

Instead of guessing (or trial-n-error) which key is the culprit, is it possible to list all my SSH keys' length?

**UPDATE:**

- Only `git pull` is giving me above error. I.e., my public key is still fine:

  ```
  $ ssh -T git@salsa.debian.org
  Welcome to GitLab, @myid-guest!
  ```
- The `ssh-keygen -lf` might not be the answer, as I'm following https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/, who recommends to use `ed25519` as default key, and who also instructs that, to generate a new ED25519 SSH key pair, do `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"`. However, my `ssh-keygen -lf` reports that

  ```
  $ ssh-keygen -lf id_ed25519.pub
  256 SHA256:PO2bk6B...
  ```

It is unlikely that the recommend ED25519 SSH key is only 256 bits long.

￼

Comment: 1. to list all keys and their size: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/given-keys-in-ssh-authorized-keys-format-can-you-determine-key-strength-easi  2. that's the right size of ED25519 key, Public keys are 256 bits in length and signatures are twice that size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you try

```
ssh-keygen -lf keygen.pub
```

Comment: @xpt : I think it is showing right as ED25519 is 256 bit only Refer this article "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#performance" where it is mentioned  Public keys are 256 bits in length and signatures are twice that size.

Comment: maybe your instance does not support ED25519, You can fallback to RSA .. 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#ed25519-ssh-keys

Comment: I generated a new ED25519 SSH key pair after I got that error. Took me a while to verify that it is working, as my situation is complicated. Any way, it is actually working. I.e., the 2048 bits requirement is ***only*** for the `RSA` keys. As for the ED25519 SSH key, that default 256 bit is good enough for GitLab! So, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You might have accidentally deleted the public key that Gitlab uses to authenticate you.
I would recommend contacting them, otherwise look up into it.

Comment: @xpt Why don't you try to reconfigure git overall. Try: sudo dpkg-reconfigure git

Comment: That "2048 bits" requirement is imposed by the server, at salsa.debian.org, as explained in OP. I don't think reconfigure git at my client side will be of any help in this situation.

Comment: @xpt I'm sorry but that's as far as I can go. Hope you can fix it, try contacting their support team.

Comment: Thanks for your help johny. The accepted answer already has a perfect solution, and, hmmm..., before your git reconfiguration suggestion actually. So, again, I'd like to take the opportunity to welcome you to the SO site. You may find that it is different from the forum-sites that you are accustomed to.